# Save results of a Django Form in a list to use it in future for the next form. [Answers from one form servers as input for next]

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am working on a project that requires to take input from user using form but the results are not supposed to be saved inside the DB. I am using a Form to show Display multiple choices to users using a list and users have to select from them but rather than saving them inside the DB, I want these to be saved in a list (or Dict ) and use them for the next step of processing.

Here is my Form

```
class DemoForm(forms.Form):
    input_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']  # example list that I show to users
    answers = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=[(c, c) for c in input_list],
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
    )
```

To process the form, this is the demo view....

```
    def show_result(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = DemoForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                future_list = form.cleaned_data['answers']

                # I want this list to be available for the next form as  the Input_list2 for DemoForm2
        else:
            form = DemoForm()
            return render(request, 'paid_for.html', {'form': form})
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You have to create models to store your data to database. Create Model -> using ModelForm instead, if you're newcomer that could help you a lot. just read the guideline clearly then you can handle it easily.

Comment: No! It is just like per user view. I am dynamically providing resulting to users after 2-3 steps. First I am getting the inputs from users and then processing them using these forms and views.

Comment: Try django-formtools (https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: If you could provide DjangoForm2 then it will be more clear and other people might understand your flow clearly. Maybe you need something like: `DjangoForm2(initiate={'input_form2': future_list})`, but not sure about how the DjangoForm2 so just guessing.

Comment: maybe https://redis.io/ can help if you don't want store it in database.